# Can I access a value in Formik before onSubmit is run?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am trying to do some maths over a value that the user inputs

```
<Form>
    <label htmlFor={`price${props.id}`}>Price</label>
       <Field
          name={`price${props.id}`}
          type="text"
       />
       <ErrorMessage name={`price${props.id}`} />
       <span> </span> //Where I want to display value
      ...
```

This is how I am using Formik. Form is simply nested inside of Formik:

```
<Formik
          initialValues={{
            [`price${props.id}`]: '',
}}

          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
              setSubmitting(false)
          }, 400)
}}>
    <Form>
     ....
    </Form>
</Formik>
```

Comment: Can you show how you're using either `<Formik>` or `withFormik()`? You can access values from there.

Comment: @larz I have edited my post to reflect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formik accepts two types of children:

1. React node
2. Function that returns a React node

Currently you are passing a React node to Formik (#1).

In order to access `values` you need to change the child to a function (#2), which is known as a render prop.

Values can then be accessed like so:

```js
<Formik 
  initialValues={/* ... */} 
  onSubmit={/* ... */}
>
  {props => (
    <form>
      {/* here we can access props.values */}
    </form>
  )}
</Formik>
```

A full list of what `props` contain can be [found here](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#children-reactreactnode--props-formikpropsvalues--reactnode).

Comment: That does work! I am now only having a problem with my submit button: ```<button type="submit">Submit</button>```. It used to work before making these changes... now it seems its having the default behavior.

Comment: I realised tha route is changing after I click the submit button. It changes to whatever values I pass to the input fields in Formik. e.g. ```/?smallPrice0=122&mediumPrice0=333&bigPrice0=111&bikePrice0=999```

Comment: To handle the form submission you can call the [`props.handleSubmit`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#handlesubmit-e-reactformeventhtmlformevent--void) function provided by Formik.

Answer (score 1):

`<Formik>` can provide a child function that will allow you to access all of it's props, including current `values` -

```
<Formik>
  {{ values } => (
    <Form>
      <label htmlFor={`price${props.id}`}>Price</label>
      <Field
        name={`price${props.id}`}
        type="text"
      />
      <ErrorMessage name={`price${props.id}`} />
      <span>
        // will show the current value, or you can do calculations
        {values[`price${props.id}`]}
      </span>
    </Form>
  )}
</Formik>
```

Comment: I am not using a render prop. I simply have Form inside of Formik without any render like that. Edited post again so that can be visualized. Thank you for your help